# Not connecting to the database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble connecting to my local MySQL database from my PHP script.

I can connect from the command line using the following

```
mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --port=8889 --user=root -p
```

but when I use the code below to connect from my PHP script, it's not working

```
$dbc = @mysqli_connect ('localhost:8889', 'root', 'root', 'test') OR die ('<p>Could not connect to the database!</p></body></html>')
```

Any ideas?

Comment: really bad idea to have the `root` password be `root`.  If you did not change it for this posted example please rush and change it right now!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't specify the port in the first argument.  It goes in the fifth spot:

```
$dbc = @mysqli_connect ('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'test', 8889)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put MySQL port as fifth argument. like this:

```
$dbc = @mysqli_connect ('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'test', 8889)
```

please look at PHP Manual about [mysqli_connect()](http://cn.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect.php) for more information.